# MS Word VBA to convert a Word document's nested list to an HTML nested list

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using MS Word VBA how can we convert the following nested list in a Word document to an html nested list. I know in Word-VBA `ActiveDocument.Lists` is a collection of all lists and `ListParagraphs`is a collection of list items in a list. But I'm unable to loop through these collections to get a handle of the following nested list in Word document:

**Word document nested list**:

[image]

**HTML nested List**:

```
<ol>
  <li>Test1</li>
  <li>Test2</li>
    <ul>
       <li>Test2a</li>
       <li>Test2b</li>
    </ul>
  <li>Test3</li>
  <li>Test4</li>
</ol>
```

**UPDATE**:

Using code from user `@TimWilliams` below I get the following result that actually treating sub-list as a separate list 2 (as shown below). But I need to know that the list 2 is indeed a nested list of list 1. How can I achieve this?

```
List: 1       Level: 1      Label: 1.     Text: Test1
List: 1       Level: 1      Label: 2.     Text: Test2
List: 1       Level: 1      Label: 3.     Text: Test3
List: 1       Level: 1      Label: 4.     Text: Test4
List: 2       Level: 2      Label: a)     Text: Test2a
List: 2       Level: 2      Label: b)     Text: Test2b
```

Comment: Maybe start with  `ListLevelNumber`  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424573/word-2010-vba-manipulating-numbered-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should get you started:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim doc As Document, l As List, lp, i, x

    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    For x = 1 To doc.Lists.Count

        Set l = doc.Lists(x)

        For i = 1 To l.ListParagraphs.Count
            Set lp = l.ListParagraphs(i).Range
            Debug.Print "List: " & x, _
                        "Level: " & lp.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber, _
                        "Label: " & lp.ListFormat.ListString, _
                        "Text: "; Replace(lp.Text, vbCr, "")

        Next i
    Next x

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** opening a fresh document and running the code above on your example list, this is the output I get.

```
List: 1       Level: 1      Label: 1.     Text: Test1
List: 1       Level: 1      Label: 2.     Text: Test2
List: 1       Level: 2      Label: a.     Text: Test2a
List: 1       Level: 2      Label: b.     Text: Test2b
List: 1       Level: 1      Label: 3.     Text: Test3
List: 1       Level: 1      Label: 4.     Text: Test4
```

Seems like our lists somehow got created differently: I used tab to indent my sub-list items and Shift-tab to get back to the top-level list.

Comment: I've added an **UPDATE** section in my post that shows results of your code and a question related to those results.

Comment: 1. I agree we were creating our lists differently. I was using `Multilevel List menu` in the Ribbon that was different output than yours. But when using your way of generating the same nested list, I'm getting your output - and that's the one I needed. Thank you for adding your `EDIT` and more importantly explaining how you generated the list (otherwise, I would have been scratching my head figuring out what's going on and how to come up with your output). 2. I like how you understood what I was after and then you provided a guideline. HTML nested list example was just for demo.